# Authenticate and Repository creation on Docker Hub

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerhub, docker-api

I'm working on a project in which I need to authenticate a user and create his repository(public) on Docker hub. I have googled a lot and explore various APIs docker offer but couldn't find any solution and example.

I need to build it in Python 3.

Comment: What's wrong with `docker login`?

Comment: As I said above, I need to authenticate external users to create repositories for them and want to implement it via API.

Comment: You need to get the details from them somehow. Then you just call the docker login api from python and create the repo? You can login and push from docker-py - https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html.